# Cron job not getting triggered on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to schedule a job using cron.

Following are the steps that i did:

sudo vi /etc/crontab

Added the following line :
* * * * * root /bin/ls  >> corn_example

Still job is not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's because you're not specifying the folder to 'ls' or a folder location for the example file to be create in.

I'd try:

```
* * * * * root /bin/ls /tmp/ >> /tmp/corn_example
```